# Storing huge volume of data will end up PHP session?

Tags: php, session, yii, session-variables

I'm trying to store huge volume of data in a session array to process it further,

```
$_SESSION['datatemp'] = $datatemp; // contains more than 100,000 records
```

after storing this array into session, **session get cleared automatically,**

Can anyone help me to find the reason ?

Comment: The solution is to avoid storing volumes of data that large in session.... session isn't intended as a replacement for a database

Comment: i need to process those records for futher sort and filter without accessing again DB

Comment: Consider using a proper cache like memcached.

Comment: Then store them in a database

Comment: @MarkBaker using memcache to store data will be ok ?

Comment: Probably, but what you shouldn't be doing is using session as a large volume datastore

Comment: @MarkBaker i am using memcahe, i have two lakh data to be cached but wihle getting from memcache it returns false

Answer (score 0):

Check if the Data is bigger than your memory_limit (php.ini).

For huge Data you can also try a filecache. Yii has a good build in, search for "CFileCache". Maybe you can split the data, and read only chunks of it from cache.